# Selenium and Ruby element mapping

Tags: ruby, selenium

I am looking to map my elements using pageObject model, although I am facing the following issue:

1:. error is thrown given I have no driver, this is ok since I only map my driver when I instantiate the class

```
     element = @driver.find_element(:id => 'username') 

      def initialize driver
         @driver = driver
         @driver.navigate.to "http://www.google.com" 
      end

     def set_username input
        element.send_keys input
     end
```

2:. in the below approach, it doesn't complain about missing driver because I am initializing it before and passing it as a global variable. but now it tries to map the element even before opening the page, which fails with "couldn't find element"

```
     element = $driver.find_element(:id => 'username') 

      def initialize 
         $driver.navigate.to "http://www.google.com" 
      end

     def set_username input
        element.send_keys input
     end
```

The question is: Is there any cheeky way I can map my elements and assign them to objects but only have them compiled/read when I actually need to use them (I only perform some action with it in the set_username, and I would only want to trigger the object mapping when utilizing it in this method for example)... I prefer not to use an existing pageObject framework...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the [Page Object model](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html), you have an object that represents the page you're testing, and objects that represent lower level HTML objects. In this case, you might have the following classes:

```
# Represents a text input HTML element...
class TextInput
  attr_reader :element

  def initialize(driver, id)
    element = driver.find_element(:id => id) 
  end

  def type(text)
    element.send_keys text
  end
end

# Represents the page you are testing...
class SomePage
  attr_reader :driver, :username

  def initialize(driver)
    @driver = driver
  end

  def username
    @username ||= TextInput.new(@driver, 'username')
  end
end
```

Once you have initialized your driver, you pass it to `SomePage`, and use it
to drive what you're doing.

```
some_page = SomePage.new(driver)
some_page.username.type("Timmy")
```

---

I can't vouch for the [page-object gem](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object) because I've never used it, but it would handle those HTML-layer objects, and give you a domain-specific language for constructing them into a page object class. Worth checking out.